# Returning multiple lists with same method Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, list, jsp, model-view-controller

I've encountered a problem that seemed easy to solve, but has shown resilience.
Namely, I'm making a web platform with a blurry search functionality. Now, a search should return a list of objects (which are all models in my case), and show them on screen in separate tabs.

BlurrySeach (for profiles):

```
public List<Profile> blurrySearch(String keyword) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Profile p where p.username LIKE :keyword order by p.username");
    query.setParameter("keyword", "%" + keyword + "%");
    List<Profile> profileList = query.list();
    session.flush();
    return profileList;
}
```

This method is an implementation from an interface:

```
  List<Profile> blurrySearch(String title);
```

Now, I can't find a way to overload this method, since changing `List<Profile>` to `List<Photos>` doesn't change the return type nor the argument list, needed to overload the method.
Changing the interface to `List blurrySearch(String title)` also doesn't change anything.
It would be inefficient to make `blurrySearchProfile`, `blurrySearchPhotos`, `blurrySearchBlogs`, `blurrySearchShops` etc. as separate methods.
How can I overload this method, to return 5 lists, like `profileList` to pass it to the `controller` and then render it on a `jsp`?

Here's the JSP code:

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Explore</h1>
            <p class="lead"> Search results! </p>
        </div>


        <!--

        <div style=" width: 75%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="galleryImage">
                <c:forEach items="${profileList}" var="profile">
                    <div class="imageWrapper">

                        <a href="<spring:url value="/users/${profile.username}"/>"
                           style="max-height: 25%; max-width:25%; left: 50%;">

                            <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/cosplay/profilePhotos/${profile.username}-prof.png"/>" alt="image"
                                 style="max-height: 90%; max-width:90%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                        </a>
                        <div style="text-align:center;">
                            <h3>${profile.username}</h3>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>${profile.description}</h3>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>

        </div> -->


        <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('Photos')">Photos</button>
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('Profiles')">Profiles</button>
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('Tutorials')">Tutorials</button>
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('Blogs')">Blogs</button>
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('Shops')">Shops</button>
        </div>
        <!-- START PHOTOS -->
        <div id="Photos" class="tab">
            <h3>Photos</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- END PHOTOS -->

        <!-- START PROFILES -->
        <div id="Profiles" class="tab">
            <h3>Profiles</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- END PROFILES -->

        <!-- START TUTORIALS -->

        <div id="Tutorials" class="tab">
            <h3>Tutorials</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- END TUTORIALS -->

        <!-- START BLOGS -->
        <div id="Blogs" class="tab">
           <h3>Blogss</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- END BLOGS  -->

        <!-- START SHOPS -->
        <div id="Shops" class="tab">
            <h3>Shops</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- END SHOPS -->


    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: generics maybe! List<E>, or if the type is restricted to some rules you can use upper/lower bound depending on the restriction rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar problem. To resolve this, we maintained 2 maps in spring xml

```
<util:map id="entityToTableMap">
        <entry key="Photos" value="tbl_photos"/>
        <entry key="Profiles" value="tbl_profiles"/>
        <entry key="Blogs" value="tbl_blogs"/>
</util:map>
<util:map id="entityToSearchFieldsMap">
       <entry key="Photos" value="field_name"/>
       <entry key="Profiles" value="username"/>
       <entry key="Blogs" value="field_name"/>
</util:map>
```

We created a repository method like this

```
@Value("#{entityToTableMap}")
private Map<String, String> entityToTableMap;    

@Value("#{entityToSearchFieldsMap}")
private Map<String, String> entityToSearchFieldsMap;

public List<T> blurrySearch(String keyword,String entityType) {
  String tableName = entityToTableMap.get(entityType);
  String searchField = entityToSearchFieldsMap.get(entityType);
  String sql ="select p from "+tableName+" p where p."+searchField+" LIKE :keyword order by p."+searchField
  ...
}
```

But, on jsp, we couldn't figure out the fields that needs to be accessed. So, we used `jdbctemplate's queryForList` method as follows

```
  @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Map<String, Object>> blurrySearch(String keyword,String entityType) {
      String tableName = entityToTableMap.get(entityType);
      String searchField = entityToSearchFieldsMap.get(entityType);
      String sql ="select p from "+tableName+" p where p."+searchField+" LIKE ? order by p."+searchField
      return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new String[]{"%"+keyword+"%"});
    }
```

And, then on jsp, we used something like this to make it generic

```
<c:forEach items="${entityList}" var="maps">
           <c:forEach items="${maps}" var="mapEntry">
              ${mapEntry['username']}
           </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```